# Problemas com laço IF

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, slider

Estou tendo problemas ao criar um laço `if` no `jquery` para que, quando o carrossel execute a função `carousel()` ele faça um laço `if`, o problema é que, ele só executa uma vez o `if`, e então para de executar o laço.

No caso, estava utilizando `$('#first-item-carousel.active')`,`$('#second-item-carousel.active')`,`$('#third-item-carousel.active')` para os laços.

JQuery

```
$('#items-principais-loja').carousel({
    interval:4000
});
$('#items-principais-loja').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    if() {
        $('#first-item-related').css({'opacity':1});
        $('#second-item-related').css({'opacity':0});
        $('#third-item-related').css({'opacity':0});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#first-item-related').css({'display':'inline-block'});
            $('#second-item-related').css({'display':'none'});
            $('#third-item-related').css({'display':'none'});
        },100);
    }else if(){
        $('#first-item-related').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#second-item-related').css({'display':'inline-block'});
        $('#third-item-related').css({'display':'none'});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#first-item-related').css({'opacity':0});
            $('#second-item-related').css({'opacity':1});
            $('#third-item-related').css({'opacity':0});
        },100);
    }else if(){
        $('#first-item-related').css({'displauy':'none'});
        $('#second-item-related').css({'displauy':'none'});
        $('#third-item-related').css({'display':'inline-block'});
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#first-item-related').css({'opacity':0});
            $('#second-item-related').css({'opacity':0});
            $('#third-item-related').css({'opacity':1});
        },100);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-e-relacionado">
    <div id="items-principais-loja" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#items-principais-loja" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#items-principais-loja" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#items-principais-loja" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active" id="first-item-carousel">
                <div class="img-holder">

                    <img src="img/loja-img1.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="second-item-carousel">
                <div class="img-holder">

                    <img src="img/loja-img2.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="third-item-carousel">
                <div class="img-holder">

                    <img src="img/loja-img2.jpg" alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div href="" id="relacionado">
        <a href="" id="first-item-related"></a>
        <a href="" id="second-item-related"></a>
        <a href="" id="third-item-related"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como posso resolver o problema ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If não é um laço, mas sim um condicional. Cada condição deve retornar um verdadeiro ou falso (true / false para ser mais exato).

Veja um simples exemplo:

```
var nome = window.prompt("digite seu nome");
if(nome != null && nome != "")
{
   alert(nome);
}
else{
    alert("Voce nao informou seu nome");
}
```

ou seja, dentro dos () do seu codigo, você deve usar expressões que retornem true ou false.

Veja este exemplo que criei, onde eu testo se um elemento esta visivel ou nao:

```
$(function(){
   var first = $(".first").is(":visible");
   var second = $(".second").is(":visible");


   $(".result").append("<p>" + first + "</p>");
   $(".result").append("<p>" + second + "</p>");
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vm4xu6er/

Comment: Não funcionou, fica entrando constantemente na primeira condição :/

Comment: Esse seu codigo esta meio confuso. Cria um JSFiddle que fica mais facil pra ajudar.

Comment: Não está confuso, é o carousel simples do bootstrap '-'